# Why does <pe:keyFilter /> and <p:keyFilter /> behave diversely in different browsers?

Tags: regex, primefaces, primefaces-extensions, keyfilter

I have the following code to restrict an input field to numbers only:

```
<p:inputText value="#{myBean.tlf}" maxlength="9">
    <pe:keyFilter regEx="/[\d\-\.]/" />
    <p:ajax />
</p:inputText>
```

It is working like I expect in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE/Edge, where it allows someone to write values that are in number keys but aren't numbers like `@|~` and so on.

Testable on [PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/keyFilter.xhtml) for `<p:keyFilter />` also.

What is the reason? Is it possibly a bug in PrimeFaces (Extensions)?

EDIT: I'm using PF 5.3, Chrome 50, Edge 20 and IE 11.

Comment: Verified for `<p:keyFilter />` with Showcase! Works like I expect in Firefox but not in Chrome/IE also.

Comment: Please everybody, post version info about PF **and** browsers!

Comment: POssible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768261/pekeyfilter-not-filtering-keys-properly-in-internet-explorer-11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [p:keyFilter not working as expected in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466526/pkeyfilter-not-working-as-expected-in-firefox)