# p:keyFilter not working as expected in Firefox

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I'm able to enter both the digits and special characters for the  p input text.

How to restrict the field that can accept only digits?  in all the browsers?

```
<p:message for="longitude" display="text"><p:autoUpdate/></p:message>
<p:inputText id="longitude" maxlength="18" style="width: 50%;" value="#{areaMB.longitude}">
<p:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9]/i" />
</p:inputText>
```

Browser Chrome Version 81.0.4044.113 (64-bit) - Only Digits are being able to enter in the field
Browser IE   Version 11.0.9600  - Only Digits are being able to enter in the field

**Problem 
But through Fire Fox**

Browser Fire Fox 75.0 (64-bit) -  Digits and Special characters are being able to enter in the field /

How to restrict the field that can accept only digits?  in all the browsers?

The Issue only exists in the Browser Fire Fox and most of the users are using this browser.

Comment: Can you specify Primefaces version and which special character is accepted? I've tried it in [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/keyFilter.xhtml) and works fine for me, with Firefox 75.0

Comment: Primefaces Version 6.2 , Spl characters like #  $ %  (

Comment: keyfilter.js changed from 6.2 and in 8 works as expected, can you upgrade? There's of course a lot of impact with that upgrade. To avoid the submit of these characters you can add a validator, re-checking the same regex, and giving the user a custom message through message tag ([here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/basic.xhtml) you can find more info).

Comment: I think there should be a way to make keyFilter working, without upgrading pf, but I'm still checking (you can also check [issue list](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues?q=KeyFilter+) for a fix) [Here's](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5110) the explanation of this issue

Comment: Yep it was fixed for 8.0. See ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This KeyFilter Firefox issue was fixed in PrimeFaces 8.0:
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5110

If you really need to restrict input to digits you can use `p:inputNumber` like this.

```xml
<p:inputNumber id="longitude" 
               maxlength="18" 
               style="width: 50%;" 
               value="#{areaMB.longitude}" 
               decimalPlaces="0"
               minValue="0" />
```

Remove `minValue` if you want to allow negative numbers.